# Rmarkdown to LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I made a presentation in RStudio with RMarkdown/Knitr - it compiles without problems to a pdf (via LaTeX Beamer).

But I cannot get the LaTeX file. Is there any way to export also the LaTeX file which should be produced in the conversion?

Comment: Add the option `output: pdf_document: keep_tex: yes`

Comment: Which is also accessible thorugh the compiling options next to the knit button.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(This was not the original accepted answer, but has since been accepted and then edited to reflect this change.)

As of late 2018, the following works:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author Person"
date: "November 26, 2018"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
---
```

Note that this answer **is** the YAML automatically inserted by the RStudio program (circa 2018) when you follow the instructions above to use the GUI to make this setting. So I assume the formatting is in the preferred style.

Comment: This is what I was looking for and it works. When exporting ,the .tex file is stored in a tmp folder. Would you know a way to store the .tex file somewhere else, say where you also save the .rmd file?

Comment: my `.tex` is put in the folder containing the rmd file.

Comment: works also if `beamer_presentation:`  is used instead of `pdf_document`. As of 2022, the `keep_tex:` part **must be indented**!

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention (although I saw it very late). Can the answer be edited to not confuse others with the **accepted answer** remark?

Comment: Yep, apparently I can, and it is done.

Comment: For me - using xelatex - that didn't work. I had to delete the colons after 'xelatex' first
   `latex_engine: xelatex`

Answer (score 17):

[image]
In RStudio:

- Click the gear - options button next to knit.
- Click output options.
- Click advanced.
- Click Keep tex source file . . .

to answer the 1st comment,
here is some sample LaTeX

```
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\NormalTok{DF <-}\KeywordTok{read.table}\NormalTok{(}
\DataTypeTok{text=}
\StringTok{"Year State Histadrut Private}
\StringTok{1985     27    26       47}
\StringTok{1993     10    14       76}
\StringTok{"}\NormalTok{,     }\DataTypeTok{header=}\OtherTok{TRUE}\NormalTok{)}

\KeywordTok{library}\NormalTok{(ggplot2)}
\KeywordTok{library}\NormalTok{(reshape2)}
```

produced by compiling

some simple RMD

````
```{r}
DF <-read.table(
text=
"Year State Histadrut Private
1985     27    26       47
1993     10    14       76
", header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
```
````

The output looks like:
[image: pdf output]

Comment: What happens to r code chunks or plots produced by code chunks? How do they translate to LaTeX?

Comment: The backend is pandoc. The code chunk can be executed, or not, and echoed into your pdf, or not. You can have the graph or table output in your pdf with or without some portion of the code that was used to produce it.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful.

Comment: The indentation appears to have changed and this doesn't work anymore. See the other answer for indentation that works as of 2022.