# How can i show my codes for functions in my appendix

Tags: r, function, document, workspace

I am writing a report and need to show the code for the functions that I have defined in R in my appendix. I also would like to make some comments at the beginning of each function saying what this function does. Is there a neat way to do this or should I just copy and paste each function from my workspace individually into a new document.

Comment: Are you using LaTeX or markdown?

Comment: LaTeX for the report itself however the appendix is allowed to be a separate file, eg. straight from R.

Comment: If LaTeX, you could use verbatim or lstlisting with [language=R], which make it easy to read. See e.g. http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf

Comment: You could also use Rmarkdown to output your code and comments to a .pdf, html, or just I believe just [straight to LaTeX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497696/rmarkdown-to-latex).

Answer (score 0):

Use `knitr`

```
install.packages("knitr")
```

Then change your `.tex` file to `.Rnw`, add (in your document preamble)

```
<<knitrOpts, echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = FALSE)
@
```

(which tells knitr to print but not evaluate the code listings)

then add your code in chunks:

```
\documentclass{article}

<<knitrOpts, echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = FALSE)
@

\begin{document}

(Rest of your report)

\appendix

The following is an example of a function that calculates the average:
<<average_fn>>=
average_fn <- function(x){
  sum(x) / length(x)
}
@

\end{document}
```

Then `knit` your document. Easiest way is to open the `.Rnw` file in RStudio, options > Global Options > Sweave. In `Compile document using:` select `knitr` in the drop down menu.

Then click `Compile PDF`