# How do you compile to pdf files in R? Problem

Tags: r, pdf, compiler-errors, miktex

I have a similar problem as already described, but the answers do not help me, that is why I am writing one more post.

I try to compile a tex file (a standard example from the web) in R, but R cannot file the pdflatex file:

```
Error running C:/Users/vica/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)
```

I tried

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:/Users/vica/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex", sep=.Platform$path.sep))
```

or

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:\\Users\\vica\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\pdflatex", sep=.Platform$path.sep))
```

(if I am wrong with the syntax), but no effect.

I added a Renviron.site file in the respective directory, writing this in it:

```
PATH=C:\\Users\\vica\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\pdflatex;"${PATH}"
```

but no effect. When I write

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

I get something strange:

```r
 Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\Users\\vica\\Documents\\R\\R-4.0.3\\bin\\x64;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Users\\vica\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\;C:\\Users\\vica\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\;C:\\Users\\vica\\anaconda3;C:\\Users\\vica\\anaconda3\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Users\\vica\\anaconda3\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\vica\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\vica\\anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\vica\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\vica\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\vica\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Users\\vica\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\;C:\\Users\\vica\\AppData\\Roaming\\TinyTeX\\bin\\win32;C:/Users/vica/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex"
>
```

I tried to compile the sweave file (exa3.tex), this is what I got:

Writing to file exa3.tex Processing code chunks with options ... You can now run (pdf)latex on 'exa3.tex'

```
Running pdflatex.exe on exa3.tex...failed Error running C:/Users/vica/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code -1073740791
```

But when I KNIT  the Rnw file, I get the pdf. This is my exa3.Rnw:

```
---
title: "MyFile1"
author: "Victoria"
date: "6 5 2021"
output: pdf_document
---

## R Markdown
 Hello, World!
```

This is my tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\title{Sweave Example 1}
\author{Victoria Knopova}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

In this example we embed parts of the examples from the
\texttt{kruskal.test} help page into a \LaTeX{} document:

\end{document}
```

Maybe I do something entirely wrong when I compile *.tex files, but I do not understand what, I only learn R...

Can somebody help me?
Thank you in advance.
Victoria

**PS: I found another way: one can  use this hint

[Rmarkdown to LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497696/rmarkdown-to-latex)

in order to translate a *.Rmd file to *.tex
**

Comment: The program is being found and run, so you are getting a status code of 1 meaning it failed when run, but it means that `pdflatex` *was found* and therefore updating the `PATH` is not required for that portion of it. There's nothing in that error that suggests that `pdflatex` couldn't find another binary, so perhaps looking at `PATH` is just a distraction. We'll need to know more about the attempted rendering. It might be useful to try to render a very small "hello world"-style rmarkdown into PDF, provide all of that rmd file and all of the output when rendering it.

Comment: Hello, @r2evans. Yes, I created a sweave file and tried to compile it. This is what I got:                                                                Writing to file exa3.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...

You can now run (pdf)latex on 'exa3.tex'
Running pdflatex.exe on exa3.tex...failed
Error running C:/Users/vica/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code -1073740791)

Comment: It's best to keep errors, warnings, and all relevant stuff for the question *in the question*, since comments are easily skipped by other readers and/or hidden by the Stack interface (when there are more than a few comments). Please [edit] your question and add that into there (as a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans, done, thanks! I added the comments to the main question.

Comment: Nor do I, since I don't have your `.Rnw` file that is failing. BTW: your code that includes `"C:\Users\vica` (single backslashes) should not work in R, they need to be double-backslashes, as in `"C:\\Users\\vica`. It's an R thing.

Comment: @r2evans, I added 2 codes. Yes, I noticed, I changed to \\, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: It's a bit difficult reading the question, please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and try to fix the formatting. (It really makes a difference. Thanks!)

Comment: @r2evans, thanks! Looks better now.... This is the first time I write something on stackoverflow, thanks for  helping!

Comment: I wonder if your `exa3.Rnw` file should be named `exa3.Rmd`, since it appears to be R-markdown. (I'm not as familiar with the R-noweb format, sorry.)

Comment: @r2evans I can create exa3.Rmd, this is no problem, similar to Rnw.  And it compiles with some tex formulae, I tried right now.  I  wonder why I cannot comlie a sweave file. I thought that if I want to integrate an R file into a tex file (as a section, for example), I need sweave. And it does not work...